# Как определить поименно *args, которые передаються с командой?

Tags: python, django

Есть менеджер-команда, которю я вызываю

```
manage.py commandname x y
```

где х и у - аргументы, которые будут использоваться "внутри".

Мне нужно передавать некоторые аргументы, которые я буду тянуть из *args:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
[...]
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        [...]
        var1 = args[0]
        var2 = args[1]
```

Как сделать, чтобы я смог передавать их поименно?:

```
manage.py commandname -otp2 x -opt1 y
```

И как потом к ним обращаться внутри функции?
Как их сделать обязательными и необязательными?

Догадуюсь, что есть простое решение, но не могу правильно поставить вопрос гуглу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации к django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/) все описано с примерами:

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--delete',
            action='store_true',
            dest='delete',
            default=False,
            help='Delete poll instead of closing it'),
        )
    # ...
```

Синтаксис option_list можно посмотреть в [документации к optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html).

Comment: спасибо. то, что нужно.